# fgets has more characters that its supposed to

Tags: c, arrays, fgets, memcpy, strcmp

Hi I'm trying to use fgets to take the string from stdin and store it in input, then it should compare with an array of words (over 50000 words long taken from a text file) using the strcmp method, but i could never get them to compare for some reason until I found out why here is my code.

```
char[] text;// <----------array is already full and working at this point I just 
char input[24];//         thought I'd include this for the memcpy
char check[24]="happ";
fgets(input,24, stdin);

for(int i=0; i < 50000; i++){
  memcpy(check, text[i], strlen(input));// this is supposed to get a substring


    if(strcmp(check, input) == 0){// this is supposed to auto complete 
        printf("%s",text[i]);}// say for example 4 letters are inputted the entire 
//array will be checked if they have the same letters then that word will be printed


printf("\n %lu %s\n",strlen(check),check);
printf("\n %lu %s\n",strlen(input),input);
```

if "happ" is inserted it should print out the last letter in the array and its
  size which it should be 4 but stdin "5 happ" I thought there might be a \n 
at the end of input so i used a temp and got the substring of input at length 
strlen(input)-1 but all i got was  "6 happ\377" please help I tried researching it but I didnt understand what was wrong with it so I didn't know what to research

Comment: A `char` array without a size doesn't really help. How big is it?

Comment: `char[] text;` This compiled ?  That too without size ?

Comment: Firstly are you aware that `fgets()` retains any `newline` at the end of the string? Secondly with `memcpy(check, text[i], strlen(input));` you are not copying the string terminator so the subsequent `strcmp()` is probably going to fall over. --> `memcpy(check, text[i], strlen(input)+1);`

Comment: I understand that english might not be your native language, but you must surely have heard of punctuation, right?

Comment: @ameyCU I just included the char[] text to show that it is used in the code I already initialized it and gave it values in my original code. I didn't know if you needed that because there are supposed to be over 50000 words stored in it, which were all taken from a text file.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the answer finally it was a simple fix

```
int cch=strlen(input-1);
if (cch > 1 && input[cch-1] == '\n')
input[cch-1] = '\0';
```